# How to use make post request async with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, post, pytest

I have a python app which I am integrating unittesting using pytest, here is an example of a .py I have, which waits for a post request:

```
@router.post(
    '/transfer'
)
async def transfer(
    *,
    transaction: DocumentTransfer = Body(..., embed=True),
    token: Token = Depends(token_middleware(token_type='transaction'))
    ):
    try:
        payload = {"id":token.identity.id, "service": json.loads(json.dumps(transaction.__dict__))} #Here I am building a payload in order to send it to another app
        headers = {'access-key': 123}
        result = httpx.post(http://my-another-app/test, json=payload, headers=headers)
        response = result.json()
        return await get_response(response)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return await get_response('Error')
```

Now I want to make the unit test with pytest, but I don't know how to do it because I have used `TestClient` from pytest, but have not used it for asyn calls.
And I would like to mock the responds that the line `result = httpx.post(http://my-another-app/test, json=payload, headers=headers)` has.

So does anyone knows how to make an async test using mock data with pytest in order to not sending the request to my another app?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is `TestClient`? please show some code related to your test function/fixture declarations